# Tool to spread the moderation workload of a Google Group

Tags: collaboration, forum, workflow

I have a Google Groups with a dozen posts per day, and 5 volunteer moderators.

Most threads are users asking questions, but others post thanks messages, tips, etc.
Some threads need an answer, some don't. But all require at least checking.

Any tool for moderators to collaborate efficiently?

Requirements:

- Moderators can mark a thread as "done" (someone has answered, or no answer deemed necessary).
- In the list of threads, see what threads are not "done" yet.
- "done" data is shared between all moderators, and can even be public (it is not a secret).
- Free.

Strongly wanted:

- Integrate directly in Google Groups' web interface or Gmail or standalone email programs. A tool that has Thunderbird/Firefox/Chrome plugins would be perfect.
- See ALL threads that are not "done" yet.